How to pass values from URL to an ODOO form
I have this landing page in ODOO:
https://www.example.com/booking-form?origin=Thessaloniki+Airport+%28SKG%29&depart=Sydney&departureDate=2024-05-16&returnDate=2024-05-18&adults=1&children=0&infants=0&transferType=ride-share
and as you can see the URL contains some information that I want to prefill in the form.
The landing page's html is the following:
<t name="Contact Us" t-name="website.contactus">
        <t t-call="website.layout">
            <t t-set="logged_partner" t-value="request.env['website.visitor']._get_visitor_from_request().partner_id"/>
            <t t-set="contactus_form_values" t-value="{                 'email_to': res_company.email,                 'name': request.params.get('name', ''),                 'phone': request.params.get('phone', ''),                 'email_from': request.params.get('email_from', ''),                 'company': request.params.get('company', ''),                 'subject': request.params.get('subject', ''),             }"/>
            <span class="hidden" data-for="contactus_form" t-att-data-values="contactus_form_values"/>
            <div id="wrap" class="oe_structure oe_empty">
                <section class="s_title parallax s_parallax_is_fixed bg-black-50 pt24 pb24 o_colored_level" data-vcss="001" data-snippet="s_title" data-scroll-background-ratio="1" data-name="Title">
                    <span class="s_parallax_bg oe_img_bg" style="background-image: url('/web/image/website.s_parallax_default_image'); background-position: 50% 0;"/>
                    <div class="o_we_bg_filter bg-black-50"/>
                    <div class="container">
                        <h1>Booking Form</h1>
                    </div>
                </section>
                <section class="s_text_block pt40 pb40 o_colored_level" data-snippet="s_text_block" data-name="Text">
                    <div class="s_allow_columns container">
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="mt-4 mt-lg-0 o_colored_level col-lg-8">
                                <p>
                                    Contact us about anything related to our company or services.<br/>
                                    We'll do our best to get back to you as soon as possible.
                                </p>
                                <section class="s_website_form" data-vcss="001" data-snippet="s_website_form" data-name="Form">
                                    <div class="container">
                                        <form id="contactus_form" action="/website/form/" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" class="o_mark_required" data-mark="*" data-model_name="mail.mail" data-success-mode="redirect" data-success-page="/contactus-thank-you" data-pre-fill="true">
                                            <div class="s_website_form_rows row s_col_no_bgcolor">
                                                <div class="mb-0 py-2 col-12 s_website_form_field s_website_form_custom s_website_form_required" data-type="char" data-name="Field">
                                                    <div class="row s_col_no_resize s_col_no_bgcolor">
                                                        <label class="col-form-label col-sm-auto s_website_form_label" style="width: 200px" for="contact1">
                                                            <span class="s_website_form_label_content">Name</span>
                                                            
                                                        <span class="s_website_form_mark"> *</span></label>
                                                        <div class="col-sm">
                                                            <input id="contact1" type="text" class="form-control s_website_form_input" name="name" required="" data-fill-with="name"/>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div data-name="Field" class="s_website_form_field mb-3 col-12 s_website_form_custom s_website_form_required" data-type="char"><div class="row s_col_no_resize s_col_no_bgcolor"><label class="col-form-label col-sm-auto s_website_form_label" style="width: 200px" for="owrem1mtipto"><span class="s_website_form_label_content">Phone Number</span><span class="s_website_form_mark"> *</span></label><div class="col-sm"><input class="form-control s_website_form_input" type="text" name="Phone Number" required="1" placeholder="" id="owrem1mtipto" data-fill-with="phone"/></div></div></div>
                                                <div class="mb-0 py-2 col-12 s_website_form_field s_website_form_required s_website_form_model_required" data-type="email" data-name="Field">
                                                    <div class="row s_col_no_resize s_col_no_bgcolor">
                                                        <label class="col-form-label col-sm-auto s_website_form_label" style="width: 200px" for="contact3">
                                                            <span class="s_website_form_label_content">Email</span>
                                                            
                                                        <span class="s_website_form_mark"> *</span></label>
                                                        <div class="col-sm">
                                                            <input id="contact3" type="email" class="form-control s_website_form_input" name="email_from" required="" data-fill-with="email"/>
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                </div>
                                                
                                                
                                                
                                                
                                                <div data-name="Field" class="s_website_form_field mb-3 col-12 s_website_form_custom" data-type="char"><div class="row s_col_no_resize s_col_no_bgcolor"><label class="col-form-label col-sm-auto s_website_form_label" style="width: 200px" for="okrnw4dmgwrr"><span class="s_website_form_label_content">Pickup Location</span></label><div class="col-sm"><input class="form-control s_website_form_input" type="text" name="Pickup Location" placeholder="" id="okrnw4dmgwrr" data-fill-with="undefined"/></div></div></div><div data-name="Field" class="s_website_form_field mb-3 col-12 s_website_form_custom" data-type="char"><div class="row s_col_no_resize s_col_no_bgcolor"><label class="col-form-label col-sm-auto s_website_form_label" style="width: 200px" for="ovidp6buq8u"><span class="s_website_form_label_content">Destination</span></label><div class="col-sm"><input class="form-control s_website_form_input" type="text" name="Destination" placeholder="" id="ovidp6buq8u" data-fill-with="undefined"/></div></div></div><div data-name="Field" class="s_website_form_field mb-3 col-12 s_website_form_custom" data-type="char"><div class="row s_col_no_resize s_col_no_bgcolor"><label class="col-form-label col-sm-auto s_website_form_label" style="width: 200px" for="o07yl9vfg3bmw"><span class="s_website_form_label_content">Pickup Date</span></label><div class="col-sm"><input class="form-control s_website_form_input" type="text" name="Pickup Date" placeholder="" id="o07yl9vfg3bmw" data-fill-with="undefined"/></div></div></div><div data-name="Field" class="s_website_form_field mb-3 col-12 s_website_form_custom" data-type="char"><div class="row s_col_no_resize s_col_no_bgcolor"><label class="col-form-label col-sm-auto s_website_form_label" style="width: 200px" for="o0kj7girt231"><span class="s_website_form_label_content">Return Date</span></label><div class="col-sm"><input class="form-control s_website_form_input" type="text" name="Return Date" placeholder="" id="o0kj7girt231" data-fill-with="undefined"/></div></div></div><div data-name="Field" class="s_website_form_field mb-3 col-12 s_website_form_custom" data-type="char"><div class="row s_col_no_resize s_col_no_bgcolor"><label class="col-form-label col-sm-auto s_website_form_label" style="width: 200px" for="ocasezgtzgos"><span class="s_website_form_label_content">Adults</span></label><div class="col-sm"><input class="form-control s_website_form_input" type="text" name="Adults" id="ocasezgtzgos"/></div></div></div><div data-name="Field" class="s_website_form_field mb-3 col-12 s_website_form_custom" data-type="char"><div class="row s_col_no_resize s_col_no_bgcolor"><label class="col-form-label col-sm-auto s_website_form_label" style="width: 200px" for="ofvlz4jmtkod"><span class="s_website_form_label_content">Children</span></label><div class="col-sm"><input class="form-control s_website_form_input" type="text" name="Children" placeholder="" id="ofvlz4jmtkod" data-fill-with="undefined"/></div></div></div><div data-name="Field" class="s_website_form_field mb-3 col-12 s_website_form_custom" data-type="char"><div class="row s_col_no_resize s_col_no_bgcolor"><label class="col-form-label col-sm-auto s_website_form_label" style="width: 200px" for="onw8u9um8dv"><span class="s_website_form_label_content">Infants</span></label><div class="col-sm"><input class="form-control s_website_form_input" type="text" name="Infants" id="onw8u9um8dv"/></div></div></div><div data-name="Field" class="s_website_form_field mb-3 col-12 s_website_form_custom" data-type="char"><div class="row s_col_no_resize s_col_no_bgcolor"><label class="col-form-label col-sm-auto s_website_form_label" style="width: 200px" for="oew9ot9i5kpj"><span class="s_website_form_label_content">Transfer Type</span></label><div class="col-sm"><input class="form-control s_website_form_input" type="text" name="Transfer Type" id="oew9ot9i5kpj" data-fill-with="undefined"/></div></div></div><div data-name="Field" class="s_website_form_field mb-3 col-12 s_website_form_custom" data-type="text"><div class="row s_col_no_resize s_col_no_bgcolor"><label class="col-form-label col-sm-auto s_website_form_label" style="width: 200px" for="ouxyjeu82zy"><span class="s_website_form_label_content">Comments</span></label><div class="col-sm"><textarea class="form-control s_website_form_input" name="Comments" placeholder="" id="ouxyjeu82zy" rows="2"/></div></div></div><div data-name="Field" class="s_website_form_field mb-3 col-12 s_website_form_custom" data-type="url"><div class="row s_col_no_resize s_col_no_bgcolor"><label class="col-form-label col-sm-auto s_website_form_label" style="width: 200px" for="o063d24dsn5ws"><span class="s_website_form_label_content">Tracking values</span></label><div class="col-sm"><input class="form-control s_website_form_input" type="url" name="Tracking values" placeholder="null" id="o063d24dsn5ws" data-fill-with="undefined"/></div></div></div><div data-name="Field" class="s_website_form_field mb-3 col-12 s_website_form_dnone"><div class="row s_col_no_resize s_col_no_bgcolor"><label class="col-form-label col-sm-auto s_website_form_label" style="width: 200px"><span class="s_website_form_label_content"/></label><div class="col-sm"><input type="hidden" class="form-control s_website_form_input" name="email_to" value="info@yourcompany.example.com"/></div></div></div><div class="mb-0 py-2 col-12 s_website_form_submit" data-name="Submit Button">
                                                    <div style="width: 200px;" class="s_website_form_label"/>
                                                    <a href="#" role="button" class="btn btn-primary s_website_form_send">Submit</a>
                                                    <span id="s_website_form_result"/>
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                        </form>
                                    </div>
                                </section>
                            </div>
                            
                            <script>
                                                document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
                                                    // Get the value of the 'pickup_location' URL parameter
                                                    const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
                                                    const pickupLocation = urlParams.get('origin');

                                                    // Fill the 'Pickup Location' input field with the value from the URL parameter
                                                    const pickupLocationInput = document.querySelector('input[name="Pickup Location"]');
                                                    if (pickupLocationInput) {
                                                        pickupLocationInput.value = pickupLocation;
                                                    }
                                                }
                            </script>
                            
                            <div class="mt-4 mt-lg-0 col-lg-4 o_colored_level">
                                <ul class="list-unstyled mb-0 ps-2">
                                    <li>My Company</li>
                                    <li><i class="fa fa-map-marker fa-fw me-2"/><span class="o_force_ltr">3575 Fake Buena Vista Avenue</span></li>
                                    <li><i class="fa fa-phone fa-fw me-2"/><span class="o_force_ltr">+1 (650) 555-0111</span></li>
                                    <li><i class="fa fa-1x fa-fw fa-envelope me-2"/>info@yourcompany.example.com</li>
                                </ul>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </section>
            </div>
        </t>
    </t>

What I tried so far:
I included the  part:
 <script>
                                                document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
                                                    // Get the value of the 'pickup_location' URL parameter
                                                    const urlParams = new URLSearchParams(window.location.search);
                                                    const pickupLocation = urlParams.get('origin');

                                                    // Fill the 'Pickup Location' input field with the value from the URL parameter
                                                    const pickupLocationInput = document.querySelector('input[name="Pickup Location"]');
                                                    if (pickupLocationInput) {
                                                        pickupLocationInput.value = pickupLocation;
                                                    }
                                                }
 </script>

to try to just prefill one value (Pickup Location) but apparently didn't work.
Is there a solution or ODOO just does not allow this customatization?
Console Errors:
.o_app[data-menu-xmlid='sale.sale_menu_root']
web.assets_web_dark.min.js:11156 .o_field_res_partner_many2one[name='partner_id'] input
web.assets_web_dark.min.js:11156 .o_website_preview[data-view-xmlid='website.homepage'] :iframe #wrapwrap .s_cover h1
web.assets_web_dark.min.js:11156 a.o_onboarding_step_action[data-method=action_open_step_company_data]
web.assets_web_dark.min.js:11156 .o_menu_systray .o_new_content_container > a
web.assets_web_dark.min.js:11156 a[data-module-xml-id="base.module_website_blog"]
booking-form:367 Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
booking-form:367 Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list
booking-form:367 Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list

but my code does not have more than 100 lines.

apparently didn't work: did anything happen? Are there any errors in your dev console? Try removing the space in your element's name; ie, Pickup_Location instead of Pickup Location.

@mykaf change it, didn't work. I will update the question with the errors

Which Odoo version are you using?

It seems to be missing a closing parenthesis...

If you want to prefill contact-us form from url parameters you should modify the template's variable contactus_form_values as given below.
request.params.get('destination_location', '') Inside the get you should specify the name of parameter passed along with URL,
and it should match with the input's name.
Eg:
<input id="contact9" type="text" class="form-control s_website_form_input" name="destination_location"/>
<xpath expr="//t[@t-set='contactus_form_values']" position="attributes">
   <attribute name="t-value">{
      'email_to': res_company.email,
      'name': request.params.get('name', ''),
      'phone': request.params.get('phone', ''),
      'email_from': request.params.get('email_from', ''),
      'company': request.params.get('company', ''),
      'subject': request.params.get('subject', ''),
      'destination_location':
      request.params.get('destination_location', '')
      }
   </attribute>
</xpath>


thanks! I was trying to edit the prefilled value.
